# Cassandra and Graphite don't expose metrics other than org.apache.cassandra.metrics.*

Tags: cassandra, graphite

I have configured apache Cassandra 2.2 to use graphite using metrics-graphite-3.1.2.jar (in the lib folder and the following metrics_reporter_graphite.yaml in /etc/cassandra/)

The problem is that I don't get any metrics other than org.apache.cassandra.metrics.+,
For example, I want to get metrics on some data on java.lang.+ but it doesn't send to Graphite.

### graphite:

```
period: 30
timeunit: 'SECONDS'
prefix: 'cassandra-clustername-node1'
hosts:
- host: 'localhost'
    port: 2003
predicate:
color: 'white'
useQualifiedName: true
patterns:
    - '^org.apache.cassandra.metrics.+'
    - '^java.lang.+'
```

Answer (score 0):

JVM related metrics will be available starting with 2.2.8 (see [CASSANDRA-12312](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-12312)). These metrics will be exposed under `jvm.*`, see [here](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/doc/source/operating/metrics.rst#jvm-metrics) for a list of options.